# how to draw a line between cells in jsf datatable?

Tags: jsf

How to draw line between cells in JSF datatable?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

#### See also:

- [w3schools CSS tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)
- [w3schools CSS tutorial - styling tables](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp)